# TextView text not wrapping on some devices

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

I have an app on the market.  It worked great on all devices that I tested on before release but everyone once and a while a user emails me with the below issue.  Please see screenshot.

[image]

The TextView text just runs off the screen instead of wrapping.  If a user is having this trouble, it happens on all TextViews in the app for them that need to wrap.  Also, as seen in the screenshot, the text also becomes white instead of black like it should be.

Out of ~1500 installs, it has been reported to me by 3 users.  So far, all 3 have been tablets and not phones.  Below are the names of the tablets:

- Samsung Galaxy Pad 10.1
- Vizio 8 inch
- Toshiba Thrive

Any ideas why this is happening to so few devices?

Comment: If possible,give a try to test the application by creating AVD with similar configuration to the listed tablets.It may give you some idea about what is going on.

Comment: I have tried that and have been unable to reproduce it on an AVD.  I will continue to try though.

Answer (score 0):

try `android:lines="2"` in the textView xml parameters

Answer (score -1):

In the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) documentation you have parameters of the TextView object such as..

- android:ellipsize (Set this to none)
- android:maxLines  (Set to a 100 or something)

Some of the above might work. Try them out. Browse through the docs until you find the correct setup for your TextView.

Comment: I can try all of that, but what explains why it is happening extremely rarely?